# Uni Assignment help (arrays and read from file) JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

My assignment requires me to have Java read a file that was given to me and use an arrays to input data from the file I believe, but I have no idea where to begin or how to start. Any help will be appreciated. This program tracks who may have a notebook that went missing from checking when the times have crossed.

[Uni assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RdR6.png)

An example file might be formatted as follows:

```
Yusif 11 13
Amber 9 14
Marco 14 17
```

---

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class NotebookTracker {
    
        public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        
        public static boolean timesCross(int start1, int end1, int start2, int end2) {
            if (end1 > start2) {
                return true;
                }
            else {
                return false;
                }
            }
        
    
        public static int getCrossingStaff(int missingtime1, int missingtime2)
        {
        
            int havenotebook = 0;
            System.out.println("Enter the number of staff in the lab: ");
            int staffnum = kbd.nextInt();
       
            for (int i = staffnum; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("Enter the staff member's name: ");
                String staffname = kbd.next();
                
            
                System.out.println("Enter the entry time: ");
                int entrytime = kbd.nextInt();
                
            
                System.out.println("Enter the exit time: ");
                int exittime = kbd.nextInt();
                
            
                if (timesCross(missingtime1, missingtime2, entrytime, exittime)) {
                    System.out.println(staffname + " might have the notebook.");
                    havenotebook += 1;
            }
    
                else {
                System.out.println(staffname + " will not have the notebook.");
                }
                    }
                    return havenotebook;
                }
            
            
            public static boolean timesCrossLate(int start1, int end1, int start2, int end2) {
            
                if (end2 <  start2 || end1 > start2) {
                    return true;
                }
            
                else {
        
                    return false;
                }
        }
            
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            
                System.out.println("What is the earliest the notebook could have been lost?");
                int earliest = kbd.nextInt();
                
                
                System.out.println("When did you notice the notebook was missing?");
                int whenmissing = kbd.nextInt();
                
                
                System.out.println("Number of staff who might have the notebook: " + getCrossingStaff(earliest, whenmissing));
            
            }
            }
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with ?

Comment: From the linked picture, it looks like there are a bunch of things in the assignment: reading from standard input, listing files in a directory, etc. Because much of the Scanner code is missing from the above program, my guess is that the first step is to supply those missing portions where data is being read.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file line by line by using the following classes ...

```
     String expected_value = "Hello, world!";
     String file ="src/test/resources/fileTest.txt";
     
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     
     do {
        String currentLine = reader.readLine();
        // Process the line here.

     }while(currentLine != null);
    
     reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need help reading the contents of the file/input using the `Scanner` class.

The Java docs on this class have some good examples on how to use `Scanner`.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Below is a simple program that can read data from a various inputs.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Yusif 11 13");
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    sb.append("Amber 9 14");
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    sb.append("Marco 14 17");
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

    final String input = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/UniAssignment.txt")).stream().map(n -> String.valueOf(n))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    //final InputStream input = System.in;
    //final String input = sb.toString();

    try (final Scanner kbd = new Scanner(input))
    {
        while (kbd.hasNext())
        {
            final String name = kbd.next();
            final int start1 = kbd.nextInt();
            final int end1 = kbd.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Name             : " + name);
            System.out.println("Time Checked Out : " + start1);
            System.out.println("Time Checked In  : " + end1);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```